# How do I get a reference from this in C++

Tags: c++, reference

I have a class whose objects have to pass a reference to themselves to another function.

I discovered that `this` is a pointer, not a reference. So how do I get the reference to the object that I'm in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get an `l-value` of yourself to return as a reference by dereferencing the `this` pointer ie:

```
return *this;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `this` is a pointer to the object, you can get the object itself by derefrencing it with `*this`.

The function :

```
void func(MyClass& obj)
{   }
```

Calling the function.

```
func(*this);
```